# Equal number of marked cells

Tags: combinatorics

In an $n\times n$ board, some cells are marked, so that the number of marked cells is divisible by $n$. Is it always possible to divide the $n^2$ cells into $n$ connected subsets, each with $n$ cells, so that all subsets contain an equal number of marked cells? (Two cells are *connected* if they share a side.)

Two easy way to divide the $n^2$ cells into $n$ sets of $n$ cells is to consider the rows or consider the columns. But it is not always the case that one of these ways must work (the x cells are marked):

x o o

x x o

o o o

Doing the split either by row of by column does not work, but taking the first row and L-shapes in the remaining two rows works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

A counterexample would be $n = 5$ with $10 = n * 2$ marked cells. Place a grid of 3 by 3 markers in a corner, place the last marker anywhere.

Any connected set containing the marker in the corner would contain at least 3 marked values, while there should be only 2 in each set.

$$
\begin{matrix}
o & o & o & o & o\\
o & o & o & o & x\\
o & o & x & x & x\\
o & o & x & x & x\\
o & o & x & x & \mathbf{x}\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not always possible.

Consider a 4x4 square with a corner 2x2 block marked. You want to split this into 4 regions with 1 marked cell each.
The marked corner cell is not adjacent to any unmarked cell, so cannot be in a region with only one marked cell.